# How to Set Next Statement in Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: visual-studio

I've seen videos of people working in debugger and dragging the `next statement arrow` around the code.

[image]

I'd like to grab the arrow and put it back a few lines, but dragging does not work (The shortcut Shift-Command-F10 works though).

How is this done on Mac? I am using version 8.2.6

Comment: Can't you right-click the wanted line and select "Set next statement" or similar?

Comment: Thanks. Completely missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may right-click on the target line and select "Set next statement".